# Adding external xsd classes to Service Endpoint Interface generated by Apache cxf

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, cxf, microservices

I have an SEI "MessageSubmitServicePortType" generated by CXF from a WSDL for calling a SOAP service.

It takes an instance of the request class i.e. "MessageSubmitRequestType" while calling the WSDL operation method. So, the call looks like following

```
endPointObject.submitMessage(requestTypeObject);
```

Within the request class , a field with `Anytype` in the WSDL is generated as an Object attribute in Java.

I am setting an instance of a class generated from an external xsd in the above Object type attribute.

So, in short,

```
requestTypeObject.setAnytype(JAXBElelment<ExternalXSD.someclass>)
```

This JAXBElement is created using the ObjectFatory class generated from the external XSD.

However, at execution I'm receiving a `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException externalxsd.someclass is not known in this context` error.

I know this can be fixed by adding `@XMLSeeAlso` to the end point class, but I don't want to do that since those classes are generated at run time.

I've also tried adding the annotation using the binding.xjb file but it doesn't seem to append the specified class in the existing annotation. I could put my `pom.xml` and `.xjb` file here if that would help.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was to download and modify the wsdl file for my use. 
I just imported the external xsd using the  tag and that resolved the issue.